# Permanently split screen (damaged touch screen)

Tags: broken-screen, multi-window

Is there any way (via app, adb or anyhow) to force Android to actively use only part of the screen AND (this is crucial) to display something else (e.g. clock or some widget) on the remaining part?

The thing is I found an old Nexus 7 and a small part of its digitizer is damaged (top part, about 1/4 of the whole screen area). I wanted to somehow permanently "split" the screen and use the remaining 3/4 for regular use and have the rest display time and date, current weather or anything else.

Ideas anyone? :)

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but this should get you going. [Resize screen for Dead touch zone](//android.stackexchange.com/q/57267)

Comment: Thanks for that. I saw it earlier and it would be actually pretty good, but the unresponsive (touch-wise) part remains useless and I wanted to have it display something....